# Search not working for spaces, exclamation mark, slashes

Tags: azure-search

When I search for a sentence like `adoption of an animal`, I don't get any results.

Looking at the generated query, I have

`&search=content_1:(/.\*adoption of an animal.\*/)&queryType=full&$count=true`

which doesn't return anything.

How can I make my query work with spaces, hyphen, exclamation marks, question marks?

Here is the predicate:

```
var actualPhraseInNamePredicate = PredicateBuilder.True<T>().And(r => r.Name.Contains(searchTerm));
```

Comment: Welcome to Sitecore Community David. Best would be to add also code so somebody can precisely give you answer with correct code

Comment: Can you please post you code. I think you are doing an "equals" and not a "contains"

Comment: There are some limitations with Azure search David so you may want to check these here: https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/search_and_indexing/sitecore_azure_search_overview#_Limitations_of_Azure